# How do I pass a a bundle from an Activity to Service from a Pending Intent?

Tags: android, service

I am trying to pass a variable(long) from an activity to a service, I have the following 
In the activity:

```
myIntent = new Intent(SetAlarm.this, Service.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
     SetAlarm.this, 
     (int)reminderId, 
     myIntent, 
     0
);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putLong("reminderId", reminderId);
myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillisec, pendingIntent);
```

In my Service:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
CurrentreminderId = (long)bundle.getLong("reminderId");
```

Somehow, I just couldn't grab this reminderId value, any ideas?? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks heaps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i always use and seems to work.
Try it out. You may be getting the extras incorrectly.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();

// see Bundle.putInt, etc.
// Bundle.putSerializable for full Objects (careful there)
b.putXXXXX("key", ITEM);  
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);

// -- later, in Activity or service
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
int i = b.getInt("key");
```

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I had but hay, I know where I've gone wrong! I've put the bundle, putting variables into the bundle after I set the pendingIntent! And that didn't get picked up, after I put it before the pendingIntent, it worked!! Thanks for all the suggestions anyway, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
```

you should do this:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
```

Comment: Tried intent.getExtras(); still couldn't pass reminderId to the service.